# Decrement operator working as addition in Python

Tags: python

I have recently started coding on python.. Today I came across a statement **10--2**.. At first, I thought it might give an error but when I compiled the code the answer came out to be 12.. I don't have any clue how was this possible.. I have knowledge about increment and decrement operators but this doesn't make sense.. If anyone of you can describe the logic it will be of great help..

Comment: Python does not have a `--` decrement operator. What you see is actually `10-(-2)`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no *increment* or *decrement* operators (i++, i--) in Python unlike some other languages(c, Java) 
If you want to do increment you need to do something like `i = i+1` or simply `i += 1`

 Here what happens is Python treats 10--2 as 10 - (-2),

That is
 `10 - (-2) =  10 + 2 = 12`
Similarly, 
`10-+2 = 10 - 2 = 8`

You can even do

```
10++2 = 12
10-+2 = 8
```